# py2app dropping wxpython (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, wxpython, osx-snow-leopard, py2app

After upgrading to Snow Leopard, I'm having trouble building my application.  It looks like py2app is building and copying over wxPython, but when I run from the buld app, it can't find wx.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by doing a clean Snow Leopard install, and installing python from Python.org, then the corresponding wxPython.  py2app I built from source.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to your own question when you finally figured it out -- it can be a great help to anyone else who runs into the same problem in the future.